# Export a table saved inside a .mat file as a .csv

Tags: matlab, csv, struct, export, matlab-table

When I load a `.mat` file, I get a variable called `gTruth` in my workspace:

```
gTruth = 
  groundTruth with properties:

          DataSource: {1001×1 cell}
    LabelDefinitions: [3×3 table]
           LabelData: [1001×3 table]
```

Now I want to export only `LabelData` to a `.csv` file. How to do this?

I'm using MATLAB R2018a.

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using?.

Comment: 9.4.0.813654 (R2018a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html):

```
data = load('input_filename.mat');
writetable(data.gTruth.LabelData,'output_filename.csv');
```

Comment: this solves my problem. sorry i forgot to accept this answer

Comment: Now i have a little problem with the format. the `[30 115 266 38;662 99 1199 43]` in the matlab table is jumbled as: `30,662,115,99,266,1199,38,43`

Comment: @J.David Please post a new question and show the complete code you're using, so it can be reproduced.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948165/converting-file-from-matlabs-table-into-csv-file-correctly
Here it is